# Select * as ALLIDS from table where user ID NOT IN (another table) while also counting how many times they occur in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

That's possibly the worst title ever composed on StackOverflow but please hear me out:

I have a Tinder style database design:

USERS

```
 ID, Name, etc, etc.. Not important
```

SWIPES

```
SwiperID, RecipientID, didLike
```

Now i'm attempting to "pull-in" a set of potential swipes for user X, which means i need to 1: SELECT ALL USER IDS THAT USER X HAS NOT SWIPED FOR, my attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID NOT IN ( SELECT recipientID FROM swipes WHERE swiperID = ? ) AND ID != ? LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Which works, however my problem comes with number 2:

I need to then take these newly found, un-swiped users and COUNT how many times each of them have been "Swiped/Not Swiped" in the past and combine it with their other user data to return i.e.

COUNT(didLike) WHERE recipientID = ? AND didLike = true

But beyond doing a For loop in code that then performs that query over and over potentially hundreds of times for each ID found, how can i combine these queries?! I have been toying with queries for far too long.

Comment: Write a subquery that gets the counts for each user, and `JOIN` it with the original query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this...
Join the user table with the swipe count, then do your filter.

`SELECT users.*, r.likes
FROM users 
INNER JOIN (
  select recipientId, sum(case when didlike=true then 1 else 0 end) as likes 
  from swipes
  group by recipientId ) r on r.recipientId = users.ID
WHERE ID NOT IN ( SELECT recipientID FROM swipes WHERE swiperID = ? ) AND ID != ? LIMIT 0 , 30`

I haven't tested this at all, but it should put you in the right direction at least.

Comment: This is actually very similar to something that i came up with.. However it seems to have a flaw, such that, if one of the users has NEVER "swiped" a user, there will be no records with their ID in the swipes table, thus excluding them from the query and missing them out

Comment: Solved, simply a matter of using a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN!